# What is the reason behind the death of Jada Bharatha's father?

Tags: bhagavata-purana

What is the reason behind the death of father of Jada Bharata? Is it a natural death (due to age) or any another?

Comment: It was natural death.- https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/9/6

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great emperor Bharata from whom India has got it's name "Bharatvarsha or Bharata" After death, he was reborn as the son of a saintly brahmana. Though full of spiritual wisdom he used to roam about like a fool. Jada means heavy or dull or fool.

Jadabhrata was the third birth of this Bharatha; in it he became aware of his previous lives and mistakes he did in those. He was determined that he would not  commit the mistakes he had done in his previous lives.

As he grew up his family/friends observed that there was something unusual about his behaviour. He became totally indifferent to the members of his family and  outside world. Most of the time  he remain silent. He did not carry out any work, If given food, he would eat otherwise he would remain starved. He preferred to be alone. Since he did not respond to anything  his family members have mistaken him as a fool, dull. Thus he was nicknamed as ‘Jaḍabharata’.

The cause of death of brahmana father of Jada Bharata was natural. He died a natural death according to [**Bhāgavata Purana**](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/5/9/6/). SB 5.9.6. It is said that he died when the proper time came. And that suggests the natural cause because no other cause is mentioned.

> evaṁ sva-tanuja ātmany anurāgāveśita-cittaḥ
> śaucādhyayana-vrata-niyama-gurv-anala-śuśrūṣaṇādy-aupakurvāṇaka-karmāṇy
> anabhiyuktāny api
>  samanuśiṣṭena bhāvyam ity asad-āgrahaḥ putram
> anuśāsya svayaṁ tāvad anadhigata-manorathaḥ kālenāpramattena svayaṁ
> gṛha eva pramatta upasaṁhṛtaḥ.
>
> **The brāhmaṇa father of Jaḍa Bharata** considered his son his heart and
> soul, and therefore he was very much attached to him. He thought it
> wise to educate his son properly, and being absorbed in this
> unsuccessful endeavor, he tried to teach his son the rules and
> regulations of brahmacarya — including the execution of the Vedic
> vows, cleanliness, study of the Vedas, the regulative methods, service
> to the spiritual master and the method of offering a fire sacrifice.
> He tried his best to teach his son in this way, but all his endeavors
> failed. In his heart he hoped that his son would be a learned scholar,
> but all his attempts were unsuccessful. Like everyone, this brāhmaṇa
> was attached to his home, and **he had forgotten that someday he would
> die. Death, however, was not forgetful. At the proper time, death
> appeared and took him away.**

---

Here We can read the full story of [**Jadabharata**](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/5/9/)